# Java parsing a file

Tags: java, parsing

I want to parse through a data file in Java. The data file has information about people each separated by semicolons ";". At the end of each line in the data file, each person has an email address. Each person can have one or more email addresses. How can I parse through the file and create a "person" object, with one or more email addresses? I keep getting an outofbounds exception at 4 and I'm not sure why.

this is one line from the data file:

```
306a;;Sampson, Brock;123 N 1st Street,Omaha,NE,68116,USA;brock_f_sampson@gmail.com,bsampson@venture.com
```

Heres my code so far:

```
if(tokens[4].contains(",")){
                String emails[] = tokens[4].split(",");
                for(String email : emails) {
                    person.addEmail(email);
                    person.setEmail(email);
                }           
            }
            else{ 
                String email = tokens[4];
                person.addEmail(email);
            }
            System.out.println(person.getEmail());




    }       
    s.close();
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use things like List or ArrayList?  Ultimately you want to have an unbounded list to put email addresses in.

Comment: it seems to be a very nice and simple homework

Comment: `String[] emails = Arrays.copyRange(tokens, 5, tokens.length - 1)` is a nice solution I'd recommend.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: I created a list of emails but it seems to give me an outofbounds exception of 4. See my new code. Any help would be appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Person` class may contain a `List<String>` field for the email addresses. Also foresee a `addEmail(String)` method to add an email to that list.

Then you can just loop your `email[]` array and add each email through the addEmail method.

The `Person` class may look like this:

```
public class Person {
    private List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addEmail(String email) {
        emails.add(email);
    }
}
```

And then you can loop your array:

```
Person person = new Person();

String emails[] = tokens[5].split(",");
for(String email : emails) {
    person.addEmail(email);
}
```

Comment: I keep getting outofbounds excepction

Answer (score 0):

Please find below a working example (Java 8):

```
package be.duo.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Parser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "306a;;Sampson, Brock;123 N 1st Street,Omaha,NE,68116,USA;brock_f_sampson@gmail.com,bsampson@venture.com";

        Parser parser = new Parser();
        Person person = parser.parsePerson(line);

        System.out.println("The emails are:");
        person.getEmails().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private Person parsePerson(String line) {
        final Person person = new Person();

        String[] tokens = line.split(";");

        String [] emails = tokens[4].split(",");
        Arrays.stream(emails).forEach(person::addEmail);

        return person;
    }

    class Person {

        private List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addEmail(String email) {
            emails.add(email);
        }

        public List<String> getEmails() {
            return emails;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of creating an array of e-mail addresses, and then assigning them to separate email variables, just leave it as an array.  If you don't know how many e-mail addresses there are going to be, why try to force a specific number?